# Merge small underlying polygons into overlaying shapefile with larger polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I have a dataset with the average rent prices saved in a vector layer (.shp). It is "street" based, so it has quite a fine resolution. I have a different dataset (containing info about crime rates) in more coarse (district) based resolution.

I want to achieve that the rent prices are aggregated in the more coarse resolution - say 3 polygons of the rent prices are together one district. I want the mean average rent price of that district.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

I'm using QGIS, but R is also fine

Comment: What settings did you use in the `join attributes by location` tool? (Use the [edit] button to add information to your question instead of posting it in the comments.)

Comment: `join attributes by location` doesn't summarize the attributes at all. It simply copies the attributes from the intersecting feature. Try `join attributes by location (summary)` if you want to summarize attributes. But this tool also doesn't do an area-weighted average; for that you have to manually calculate area-weighted values.

Comment: so probably the best way would than to rasterize the smaller polygon layer and then calculate the area weighted average of the larger polygon layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which finally worked for me was:

- rasterizing the rent price polygons using v.to.rast (GRASS) plugin of QGIS. Then in R i applied following code:

  ```
      # Required packages
      library(raster)
      library(rgdal)

      # import data
      rent <- raster("Data/BRW_2012_1.tif")
      districts <- shapefile("Data/districts.shp")

      # Calculate Area Weighted Mean
      rent.mean <- extract(rent, districts, weights=TRUE, normalizeWeights=TRUE,         fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, sp=TRUE)

       weighted.rent <- data.frame(rent.mean)

      writeOGR(districts,driver="ESRI Shapefile",dsn="Data", layer="Rent_weighted")
  ```

Thanks for your input!